# Symmetry relations of a Hamiltonian (Mirror, Chiral, Inversion, Rotation)

Tags: symmetry, reflection, hamiltonian, rotation

I'm reading a paper https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.104.235136. Regarding Eq. (4)~(6), I have the following questions:

(A) Eq. (5) shows a mirror symmetry relation $M_z H \left( k_x , k_y , k_z \right) M_z ^{-1} = H \left(k_x , k_y, -k_z \right)$. Why was the right-hand side written as $H \left(k_x , k_y, -k_z \right)$ instead of $H \left( k_x , k_y, +k_z \right)$? Likewise, Eq. (4) is about the inversion symmetry: $P H\left( \mathbf k \right) P^{-1} = H\left( - \mathbf k \right)$. Why should we use $H\left( - \mathbf k \right)$, instead of $H\left( +\mathbf k \right)$?

(B) Eq. (6), $C H\left( k_x , k_y \right) C^{-1} = - H\left( k_x , k_y \right)$, does not have $k_z$ because the Hamiltonian has a chiral symmetry only in the mirror plane. If the Hamiltonian has a chiral symmetry for all the $k$-points, how can we write the relation? $C H\left( k_x , k_y , k_z \right) C^{-1} = - H\left( k_x , k_y , +k_z \right)$? Or $C H\left( k_x , k_y , k_z \right) C^{-1} = - H\left( k_x , k_y , -k_z \right)$?

(C) If the Hamiltonian has a rotational symmetry (e.g., 2-fold), is the relation $\hat R H\left( \mathbf k \right) {\hat R}^{-1} = H\left( R {\mathbf k} \right)$ correct? Or $\hat R H\left( \mathbf k \right) {\hat R}^{-1} = H\left( \mathbf k \right)$?

(D) Let's assume that there are two systems described by $H_1$ and $H_2$. Although each system does not have a mirror symmetry, reflecting $H_2$ about $z$-normal plane completely overlaps to $H_1$ (like left and right hands). Then, how can I express this? $M_z H_1 \left( k_x , k_y, k_z \right) M_z^{-1} = H_2 \left(k_x , k_y, +k_z \right)$? Or $M_z H_1 \left( k_x , k_y, k_z \right) M_z^{-1} = H_2 \left(k_x , k_y, -k_z \right)$?

Answer (score 0):

(A) You can think of it as definition. Here, it assumes that the plane of mirror is the xy-plane. For an intuitive picture, think about an object sitting below the xy-plane (at some negative z value). Now place a mirror at z = 0, then the reflection of the object is sitting above the xy-plane and at the positive z value.
For inversion, again consider it the definition. The action of inversion takes your parameter (in this case, $k$) to its negative: ($k_x$,$k_y$,$k_z$)$\rightarrow$($-k_x$,$-k_y$,$-k_z$). Physically, the action of inversion is the reflection about a point (not a plane, as in the case of mirror symmetry).

(B) Assuming the chiral axis is the z-axis, the one with the $+k_z$ is the correct one.

(C) $Rk$ physically doesn't make sense. Thus, the second expression is the correct one.

(D) The second way. $M_z$$H_1$($k_x$,$k_y$,$k_z$)$M_z^{-1}$ = $H_1$($k_x$,$k_y$,$-k_z$) = $H_2$($k_x$,$k_y$,$k_z$)